# google maps user location not loading

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I can create a webpage that takes the name, address, lat and long of many businesses in a specific city and have put them into an embedded google map on my page.  The connection to the database works, putting up the markers on the map works, however what I can't figure out from any examples, including those on Googles developers page, is how to user a user's location instead of the default coord in the googlemap.js file.  What am I missing here?

```
var map;
var geocoder;

function loadMap() {

if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
        {
            zoom: 14,
            center: pos
        });
});
}

     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    //   position: pune,
         map: map
     });

     var cdata = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('data').innerHTML); 
     geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     codeAddress(cdata);

     var allData = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('allData').innerHTML);
     showAllHonda(allData)
}
function showAllHonda(allData) {
var infoWind = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
Array.prototype.forEach.call(allData, function(data){
    var content = document.createElement('div');
    var strong = document.createElement('strong');
    strong.textContent = data.name;
    content.appendChild(strong);


    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng),
        map: map
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function(){
        infoWind.setContent(content);
        infoWind.open(map, marker);
    })

})
}


function codeAddress(cdata) {
Array.prototype.forEach.call(cdata, function(data){
    var address = data.name + ' ' + data.address;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var points = {};
            points.id = data.id;
            points.lat = map.getCenter().lat();
            points.lng = map.getCenter().lng();
            updateHondaWithLatLng(points);
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status)
        }
});
});
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  Adding the missing HTML and running this over `https:` centers the map on my location (or at least what HTML5 geolocation returns for my location). ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/hxy04o1b/2/))

Answer (score 0):

To find user's position you can use `navigator.geolocation` :

```js
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        var pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
            {
                zoom: 14,
                center: pos
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: Worth noting, `getCurrentPosition()` expects to be called from a secure origin (HTTPS).

Comment: OK, post has been edited but the browser doesn't ask for permission for my current location.  Currently using localhost as a test server